# How to return two models in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have this function that will be called in the controller:

```
public EditViewModel PostEditViewModel(EditViewModel model)
    {            
        using (var db = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            var prod = db.Products.Where(x => x.Id == model.Id).Single();
            {
                prod.Id = model.Id;
                ...
                //I need something like this:
                //prod.CategoryID = model.CategoryList.CatId
                //but obviously intellisense tells me that after the dot of CategoryList, only methods of that list can be called.
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

and this is my ViewModel:

```
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    ...
    public IEnumerable<Categories> CategoryList { get; set; }

    public class Categories {
    public int ProdId { get; set; }
    public int? CatId { get; set; }
    public string CatName { get; set; }
    }
```

how do I call the CategoryList through my EditViewModel so that I can edit the Category of a specific product through HTML.DropdownList?

Comment: Can you post the razor/markup for your DropDownList in the view?

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("CategoriesDropdown", Model.CategoryName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your product model have `CategoryId` property (I just can't see it in your question) and you using strongly typed View You always can use this overload of `DropDownListBoxFor()` helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.CategoryId,
    new SelectList(Model.CategoryList, "CatId", "CatName")
)
```

But actually i **recomend** you to use `SelectListItem` in `ViewModels` for all your dropdowns, becouse it's really bad practice - put domain entity on your `View`

Than your `ViewModel` will be like:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int CategoryId { get; set; } 
...
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
```

And on the View you can do this way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoryId, Model.CategoryList)
```

In your **GET** `ViewModel` `Controller` you can initialize your `CategoryList` like this:

```
        model.CategoryList = db.Categories.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = x.Name,
                Value = x.Id.ToString()
            });
```

It really helps you to get your Views cleaner.

Comment: it says the value can't be null, but thanks for the insight, Teo

Comment: Initi your select list :) selectlistitem list and it will worr

Comment: I'm sorry, Teo, as you can assume, I'm really new to MVC. As you suggested I used SelectListItem, but now, having removed the IEnumerable<Categories> CategoryList { get; set; } part, I can't convert my model to a list:

Comment: model.CategoryList = (from c in db.Categories
                                      orderby c.Name
                                      select new EditViewModel
                                      {
                                          CategoryId = c.Id,
                                          CategoryName = c.Name
                                      }).ToList();

Comment: here you are, i updated the answer =) how you can init your CategoryList

Comment: Thanks again Teo, it really helped me understand more but on the other hand I think it's getting complicated by the hour  :) , 'cause new errors keep coming, like LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method

Comment: Are you sure that you write exactly what i post? Wierd error

Comment: Yes, I tried to comment: Value = x.Id.ToString() and it works, so the problem is really on that line.

Comment: And without tostring? If not then convert.tostring(x.id). But it's really wierd error it should work

Comment: without .ToString(), it cannot convert int to string. with convert it still doesn't recognize the ToString() method.

Comment: Something wrong with your linq... Try to search around about this error

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `CategoryList` is used to populate the items in your DropDownList, and `CatId` is the property on your view model that captures the ID value of the selected category.

If that is the case, you can just assign it like so:

```
if (model.CatId.HasValue) 
{
  prod.CategoryID = model.CatId.Value;
}
```

Comment: The problem is, having an EditViewModel model, I can't call the CategoryList. It doesn't call CatId, but CategoryList. Like this: if (model.CategoryList

Comment: Right, I re-read your original post and see that CatId is just a prop of the Categories class. You'll need to add a prop to your view model. The approach suggested by teo van kot should work if you make sure CategoryList is initialized before rendering your view.

Answer (score 0):

If I not mistaken and I understood you, you should to create class `EditViewModel` in this class create the fields:

```
public int Id{ get; set; }
...
public IEnumerable<Categories> CategoryList { get; set; }
```

Next, in your controller, you should use the following code:

```
var prod = db.Products.Where(x => x.Id == model.Id).Single();
            {
                prod.Id = model.Id;
                ...
                prod.CategoryID = model.CategoryList.Select(m => m.CatId)
                //but Select returned the List of CatId, I suggest thet prod.CategoryID is List               
            }
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: It says it cannot implicitly convert IEnumerable<int?> to 'int?'

Comment: @JennaO'Connor yes, of course, because the Select method return the IEnumerable type. How I wrote in comment section, I suggest thet prod.CategoryID is List, or you can use the `prod.CategoryID = model.Category List.Select(m => m.CatId).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Thanks! But now, it says: value cannot be null, Parameter name: source and points the line you suggested me: prod.Category.Id = model.CategoryList.Select(m => m.CatId).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @JennaO'Connor Check the CategoryList is not empty